# how to decipher this error with "react-native run-android --variant=release"?

Tags: react-native

I'm running the command in the subject line and the following info is written to the console:

```
Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease FAILED
```

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>   135 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 133 up-to-date
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease'.

```
Could not read path'C:\s\ReactNative\MyApp\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\release\0\lib\arm64-v8a'.
```

Is the "what went wrong" section simply a "symptom" of deprecated Gradle features being used in the build?  The console output says to use '--warning-mode all' to show individual deprecation warnings but the following commands are invalid:

transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease --warning-mode all
react-native run-android --variant=release --warning-mode=all

What specific command can I execute to get a list of the individual deprecation warnings?

Comment: Can you add the build.gradle file of the app?

Comment: @Sunny - I copied the build.gradle to the Javascript section of the following jsbin for your review: https://jsbin.com/vobuxin/edit?html,js,output